# How do I migrate Core Data data to a React Native application?

Tags: ios, sqlite, react-native

I have an iOS application that uses the Core Data framework. I'm migrating the application from Objective-C/Swift to TypeScript + React Native. My Core Data configuration uses SQLite as a backend.

The application has an existing user base who may be (quite understandably) frustrated if they lose access to all the data they have in the current version, so if possible, I'd like to mitigate this possibility.

I recognize that I can access an SQLite database in TypeScript/React Native, so I think I might be able to work with the existing databases/schema; I'll just need to know exactly how to do so.

Comment: have you looked into [this](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage)? Seems like you'd be able to access your sqlite db that way.

Comment: @matkv I have some idea of how to import an SQLite database into React Native. What I need to know is how to make the app work with the existing database. For example, how do I safely interact with the database? Like, what do I need to do in order to not mess things up? For example, do I need to worry about what Z_ENT in my tables is, or can I pick out only the columns that are directly relevant to my use of the database and ignore the rest?